# C++ random_shuffle produces same result

Tags: c++

I was testing the random_shuffle function template and was able to generate different output on my MacBook. However, it is different when I try it on my friend's Windows machine.

The program will try to spawn 5 `int` and swap them randomly. It was later converted to `char` for some other uses, that's not really important.

The `randPerm()` function will initialize a `vector` and perform swapping, then return as an array. This function will be called 2 times due to the POPULATION_SIZE constant defined above. Later, the `chromosome` 2D array will be filled with respective characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// constant
const int NUM_OF_GENE = 5;
const int POPULATION_SIZE = 2;
const char CITIES[NUM_OF_GENE] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

// chromosome structure
char chromosome[POPULATION_SIZE][NUM_OF_GENE];

// function prototypes
int generateSeed(int i);
int * randPerm();
void initializeChromosome();
void printChromosome();


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    initializeChromosome();
    printChromosome();
    return 0;
}

// seed generator
int generateSeed(int i) {
    return rand() % i;
}

// return a randomly permutated array
int * randPerm() {
    static int arr[NUM_OF_GENE];

    // give some randomness
    srand ( unsigned ( time(0) ) );
    vector<int> myVector;

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_OF_GENE; i++) {
        myVector.push_back(i);
    }

    random_shuffle(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    random_shuffle(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), generateSeed);
    copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), arr);

    return arr;
}

void initializeChromosome() {
    for (int i=0; i<POPULATION_SIZE; i++) {
        int * randArr = randPerm();

        // allocate cities (in char) into the chromosome array
        for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_GENE; j++) {
            chromosome[i][j] = CITIES[randArr[j]];
        }
    }
}

void printChromosome() {
    for (int i=0; i<POPULATION_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_GENE; j++) {
            cout << chromosome[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

**The result on my Mac** Gets different result everytime
[image]

**The result on Windows machine**

Even tested with CodeBlocks, Visual Studio 2017, and even online c++ compilers. Also tested with different `GCC` versions. My Mac is using `GCC 4.2.1`

```
B A D E C 
B A D E C
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)? *(deprecated in C++14) (removed in C++17)*. For good reasons.

Comment: This boils down to "why does rand() return the same values", doesn't it? Or does it return different numbers but your code messes up?

Comment: Use srand() only *once* so you don't generate the exact same seed.  time() does not increment infinitely fast.

Comment: @HansPassant your suggestion was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion from HansPassant was helpful. By removing the `srand()` function from the loop, I am able to achieve randomness again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// constant
const int NUM_OF_GENE = 5;
const int POPULATION_SIZE = 2;
const char CITIES[NUM_OF_GENE] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
//const int CITIES[NUM_OF_GENE] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

// chromosome structure
char chromosome[POPULATION_SIZE][NUM_OF_GENE];

// function prototypes
int generateSeed(int i);
int * randPerm();
void initializeChromosome();
void printChromosome();


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    srand ( unsigned ( time(0) ) );

    initializeChromosome();
    printChromosome();
    return 0;
}

int generateSeed(int i) {
    return rand() % i;
}

// return a randomly permutated array
int * randPerm() {
    static int arr[NUM_OF_GENE];

    vector<int> myVector;

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_OF_GENE; i++) {
        myVector.push_back(i);
    }

    random_shuffle(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    random_shuffle(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), generateSeed);
    copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), arr);

    return arr;
}

void initializeChromosome() {
    for (int i=0; i<POPULATION_SIZE; i++) {
        int * randArr = randPerm();

        // allocate cities (in char) into the chromosome array
        for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_GENE; j++) {
            chromosome[i][j] = CITIES[randArr[j]];
        }
    }
}

void printChromosome() {
    for (int i=0; i<POPULATION_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_GENE; j++) {
            cout << chromosome[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```